# execvp does not termiante and it hangs for ever the child process

Tags: execvp, waitpid

I am trying to solve one issue that I have with the below C++ code:

```
int pid;
int status;
if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
  ALOGI("1.TEST-POINT->ERROR");
  exit(1);
}
else if (pid == 0) {
  ALOGI("Executing cool");
  char* argument_list[] = {const_cast<char*>("/bin/cool"), const_cast<char*>("/data/cool.bin"), nullptr};
  execvp(const_cast<char*>("/bin/cool"), argument_list)
  ALOGI("Done Executing StoreKeybox");
} else {
  ALOGI("Parent process");
  // TODO:
  // wait for child pid, check status, respond accordingly
  int tpid;
  do {
    tpid = wait(&status);
    if(tpid != pid) process_terminated(tpid);
  } while(tpid != pid);
}
```

When executing it seems it works rather nice but the cool process never seems to end.
When I execute the cool executable manually with the same parameter it works fine and it terminates afterwards.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem if you replace `/bin/cool` with `/bin/true`?  That will tell us whether the problem is with the code you have shown, or whether the `/bin/cool` program (which you have told us nothing about) is behaving unpredictably for some other reason.

Comment: Also, please turn this code snippet into a [mcve] to rule out surrounding code causing issues.

Comment: Remember that `execvp`, if successful, *replaces* the current process and does not return.  The wording of your messages suggests you are thinking that `ALOGI("Done Executing StoreKeybox");` would execute when `/bin/cool` finishes, but in fact it will only execute if the `execvp` fails (e.g. if `/bin/cool` cannot be found).  Is that the behavior you are seeing?  If you want to do something after `/bin/cool` is done, you do it in the *parent* following a successful return from `wait()`.

Comment: So my guess is that `/bin/cool` actually *is* terminating as it should, and you are just getting confused because of not seeing the `Done Executing StoreKeybox` message.